# SQL Server 2016 - Dynamic Data Masking (DDM)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, data-masking

Does anyone know if DDM has to be enabled before it can be used (and if so how), or are there only certain versions of SQL Server 2016 that have this functionality as trying to run:

```
ALTER Table Employee
ALTER COLUMN NAME ADD MASKED WITH (FUNCTION='DEFAULT()')
```

results in the following error:

> Msg 534, Level 15, State 100, Line 4 'ADD MASKED' failed because it is
>   not supported in the edition of this SQL Server instance
>   'DELL-001\SQLEXPRESS01'. See books online for more details on feature
>   support in different SQL Server editions.

The version of SQL I have installed is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR) (KB3194716) - 13.0.1722.0 (X64)
>   Sep 26 2016 13:17:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express
>   Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Home 6.3  (Build 14393: )

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This wasn't available in any edition lower than standard when SQL Server 2016 was released.

However recently SP1 was released which does enhance the functionality of lower versions quite considerably.

So you just need to install SP1.

[image]

[Image Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/)